# C/C++ libraries for HTTP programming

Tags: c++, c, http, servlets, tcplistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ - Any good web server library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486818/c-c-any-good-web-server-library)

What well known C/C++ libraries are out there that could allow one to implement servlets, or at least provide most of the essentials for dealing with HTTP/CGI protocols such as http headers, error codes, cookies, GET/POST etc.

So far I have only found [CPPSERV](http://www.total-knowledge.com/progs/cppserv/index.html).

EDIT:  Looking for server side solutions.

Comment: Haven't started yet, could be either, would choose based on what's available to me.

Comment: This is rather similar to [a question I asked some time back.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342921/c-or-c-http-daemon-in-a-thread)  Short answer: [GNU libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/)

Comment: See [
C/C++ - Any good web server library?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486818/c-c-any-good-web-server-library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to write your servlet as an Apache module - Apache itself then acts as the HTTP server-side library.

Answer (score 3):

[Tntnet](http://www.tntnet.org)

Comment: I have good experience with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one in C with ridiculous performance characteristics: [ry's http-parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser).

Comment: Now down to 40 bytes, how lucky we are that they fought to gain those 8 superfluous bytes oO

Answer (score 2):

[CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main) and [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) both spring to mind, given your requirements.

The official [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) library can also operate in a "servlet" mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a look on [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main) web framework, it has all you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/aclcpp/.

This library supports HTTP Servlet just like Java Servlet, written by C++, which includes

- HttpServlet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
- HttpSession
- HttpCookie

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck plugging into [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/home), although I've never tried.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend looking at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) given curl's popular usage.

Comment: `libcurl` is a client-side HTTP library, I believe the OP is looking for a server-side library.

Comment: Yes, I apologize for not being explicit.